# Prove that there exist infinitely many sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove this only using Empty Set Axiom, Axiom of Extensionality, Pairs, Unions, and the Comprehension Scheme?

Answer (score 4):

You can use just the first three axioms, actually. But you'll have to resort to induction in the meta-theory, and meta-theoretic arguments. Denote by $T$ the first three axioms.

Define $S_0=\varnothing$, and $S_{n+1}=\{S_n,S_n\}=\{S_n\}$. Then $T$ proves that if $S_n$ exists, then $S_{n+1}$ exists, because $S_{n+1}$ is a pair constructed from $S_n$. Since $T$ proves that $S_0$ exists, as it is the empty set, for every $n$, $T$ proves that $S_n$ exists.

Next, by induction, $T$ proves that if $n<k$ then $S_n\neq S_k$. For $k=0$ this holds vacuously.

Suppose it holds for $k$, and assume by contradiction that for some $m\leq k$ we have $S_m=S_{k+1}$, pick the least such $m$. By extensionality this means that $S_m$ and $S_{k+1}$ have the same elements, and since $S_{k+1}\neq\varnothing$ we have that $m>0$.

Therefore $S_k\in S_{k+1}=S_m$, so $S_k\in S_m$. Since $S_m=\{S_{m-1}\}$ we have that $S_k=S_{m-1}$, but $m\leq k$ therefore $m-1<k$. This is a contradiction to the induction hypothesis that for all $n<k$, $S_n\neq S_k$.

So $T$ proves that for all $n,k$ we have $S_n\neq S_k$. Therefore $T$ proves the existence of infinitely many sets.

Answer (score 3):

If there were finitely many, say $S_1,\ldots, S_n$, then the axioms of Union and Pairs would imply that $S=\{S_1,\ldots,S_n\}$ is a set. Now consider the set $B=\{x\in S: x\not\in x\}$ which exists by Comprehension. If $B\in S$ we would get a contradiction. Thus by Extensionality we have that $B\neq S_i$ for any $i$. Thus there are infinitely many sets.

The Axiom of Empty set is only important in that it guarantees our domain is non-empty.